# Django-allauth: being taken to signup form after facebook authentication

Tags: django, django-allauth

After I sign in with facebook, I am taken to a signup form which says `You are about to use your Facebook account to login to example.com. As a final step, please complete the following form:`

The username field is empty while the email-optional field has been filled up already.

When I try to enter any value, there is an error prompt that says `An account already exists with this e-mail address. Please sign in to that account first, then connect your Facebook account.`

I don't understand this, for Sign in, I have to enter a username and a password. I haven't setup a username and a password, so I cannot sign in, except try to sign in via Facebook and have the above process repeated again.

From the admin, I can see that a new user has been created in the `Users` table but no password set up, same in `Social Accounts` table.

Comment: For the email error, have you checked in the admin that there actually isn't another user with that email address?

Comment: @Leticia there is, but after I delete it from both the Users table and the Social Accounts table, and try to sign in again with all tables empty-- now I am again taken to this sign up form which tells me that an account already exists with this email address. i.e It is automatically creating a user account but still asks me to sign up, so I cannot actually login using facebook even though facebook has authenticated me already.

Comment: @Leticia I made this changes and it works, set `'VERIFIED_EMAIL': True` in SOCIAL_ACCOUNT_PROVIDERS. I don't know what that is to be honest, thought. Now I am not being taken to some signup page.